# Make Tomcat echo requesting origin in Access-Control-Allow-Origin (to avoid “must not be the wildcard when credentials mode is 'include'”)

Tags: tomcat, cors, fetch-api

I try to develop a small example web app for a presentation about React.
I will use React for the frontend, (running under localhost:3000) and Tomcat 9 (running under localhost:8080) and use the HTML5 fetch API to make requests.

My goal is to give to the audience (which will be connected to the same local network) the ability to connect to the application with their browsers, and maintain sessions.

My understanding of networking is very shallow, and thus I always fail to have this working.

My current (failed) approach is this:

1. I run **ifconfig** to get my ip address (like http://192.168.0.18) and tell this to the audience, so they connect to http://192.168.0.18:3000 which is the frontend app.
2. Use the same IP, but with port 8080 to define the backend URL base, and make the fetch:

   ```
   const SERVER_BASE_URL = "http://192.168.0.18:8080";
   return fetch(SERVER_BASE_URL+"/graphql", {
       method:"POST",
       body: JSON.stringify({
           query:query,
           params:params
       }),
       mode:"cors",
       credentials:"include"
   });
   ```
3. On Tomcat, I try to enable the CORS support by adding headers on my Servlet implementation class:

   ```
   @Override
   public void service(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res) throws ServletException, IOException {
       HttpServletRequest httpReq = (HttpServletRequest)req;
       HttpServletResponse httpRes = (HttpServletResponse)res;
       httpRes.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin","*");
       //...
   }
   ```

So far, I can see the request going on in my browser's network tab, and the sessions variables seems to be maintained correctly.

But the browser refuses to handle the response saying:

> Failed to load http://192.168.0.18:8080/graphql: The value of the
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header in the response must not be the
>   wildcard '*' when the request's credentials mode is 'include'. Origin
>   'http://192.168.0.18:3000' is therefore not allowed access.

So, I tried setting the fetch parameter credentials to "omit". Then, the error disappears, but so does the session.

My next idea would be, as the error mentions, to replace the `*` in the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header with the exact origin that I want to allow. The problem is for my case, this contains my local IP address, and I cannot know it in advance.

**My question**:

Is there any way to **either** get a predictable origin name, so I can use this for my client side application and say Tomcat to allow that, instead of using the `*` symbol, **or** Having Access-Control-Allow-Origin:* working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Origin` header in the request contains the origin from which the request was sent, and you can get that value from your code using `httpReq.getHeader("Origin")`.

So rather than doing `httpRes.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin","*")`, you can do:

```
httpRes.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", httpReq.getHeader("Origin"))
```